# Does this integral converge when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}\geq1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Fix a small $\delta>0$ and let $p,q>1$. Consider the integral

$$I(p,q):=\int\limits_{1-\delta}^{1+\delta}
\int\limits_{y/2}^{2y}\frac{1}{|y-x|^{\frac{1}{p}}|1-x|^{\frac{1}{q}}}
\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y.
$$

I am trying to show that $I(p,q)$ diverges if $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}\geq 1$. I am not sure this is even the case ? Any hints on how to handle this?

Remark: This seems to be related to the failure of the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev  inequality (HLS) at the endpoint $p=1$. HLS reads:

If $1<p,q<\infty$, $f\in L^p$ and

$$Tf(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{\gamma}}dy$$

Then   $$\|Tf\|_q\leq \|f\|_p$$
if and only if
$$\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}=1-\frac{\gamma}{n}.$$

Many thanks.

Comment: Are p and q integers? Because if they are, then the only possible case for (1/p) + (1/q) >= 1 is p = q = 2, if p or q were > 2 then (1/p) + (1/q) < 1 for sure

Comment: This should also be a function of $\delta$ no?

Comment: Reversing the order of integration should make it easier.

Comment: @Rob Bland, Unfortunately, $p,q$ are real.

Comment: @ Gregory. The $\delta$ is a fixed small constant. Think of the problem with $\delta=1/1000$.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith. Of course, changing the order of integration is a classical tool for estimating integrals, but it does not seem to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the $x$ integral into two

$$ \int_{y/2}^{2y} = \int_{y/2}^{(1+y)/2} + \int_{(1+y)/2}^{2y} $$

If $y < 1$:

$$ \int_{y/2}^{(1+y)/2} \lesssim |y/2|^{1-1/p} |1-y|^{-1/q} $$

and

$$ \int_{(1+y)/2}^{2y} \lesssim |1-y|^{-1/p} |2y-1|^{1-1/q} $$

If $y > 1 $:

$$ \int_{y/2}^{(1+y)/2} \lesssim |1 - y|^{-1/p} |1-y/2|^{1-1/q} $$

and

$$ \int_{(1+y)/2}^{2y} \lesssim |y|^{1-1/p} |1-y|^{-1/q} $$

Note: Each of these integrals put the singular term in $L^1$ and the other term in $L^\infty$. E.g. for the first one, since $y < 1$ we have $(1+y)/2 < 1$ so $|1-x| > |1-y|/2$. So the integral becomes
$$ \leq 2^{1/q}|1-y|^{-1/q} \int_{y/2}^{(1+y)/2} |x-y|^{-1/p}~ dx $$
and the interior integral can be evaluated explicitly. The other terms are treated similarly.

---

So the integral is bounded by

$$ \int_{1-\delta}^{1+\delta} |y|^{1-1/p} |1-y|^{-1/q} + |2y-1|^{1-1/q} |1-y|^{-1/p} ~dy $$

and so your $I(p,q)$ should converge.